# New User - Installing Applications ie Android SDK - Where To ? ( Equivalent of Program Files ? )

Tags: 13.04, sudo, filemanager, chown

it is taking me some time to find my way around Ubuntu and while I know I can Sudo an App like PCManFM to create directories I do not know where the best place to create a folder for the Android SDK ( http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html ) which is a zip file.

To create from the root I have to sudo then Chown ( although I do not know the right group ) which seems a long way round....

So in summary where is Ubuntus equivalent 'Program Files' folder where as a user I have full control with out going sudo each time ?

If there is not one advice would be welcome.

Thanks

T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To locate specific packages (software) open the terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> and type the following command: `locate [packagename]` where `packagename` is the exact name of your package.

You could also manually look for your software in `/usr/share/` or `/usr/lib/`

But if you want a location for the Android SDK directory I would highly recommend you put it in your `Home` directory since you do not have full privileges in the `/usr/` directory by default.

Answer (score 1):

The only location where your user has full control is your home folder - anywhere else on the system will be locked down by default and will require sudo. This is on purpose to make it harder to mess things up.

The best places to install the android SDK would be:

- ~/local/android-sdk/  - under your home folder, won't require special permissions
- /usr/local/share/android-sdk/  - anywhere under /usr/local/ would be okay
- /opt/android-sdk/  - fairly standard location for big standalone software like the android SDK

What I usually do is make sure my user is a member of the 'adm' group, then make sure that /usr/local and /opt are owned by that group and are set with group-write permissions, then install things there.  That will allow you to make changes inside of those without having to use sudo.

The purposes of the various directories can be found in the Linux File Hierarchy Standard:

http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html